Knex migration not working with node on windows
I'm trying to run the command npm run update:db, and I'm having errors. Below is what the command runs (as it would appear in the package.json files):
"update:db": "cd ../db && npm run build && npm run update",
"build": "npm i && tsc",
    "knex": "npm i && npx ts-node node_modules/.bin/knex",
    "update": "npm i && tsc && npm run knex -- migrate:rollback && npm run knex -- migrate:latest && npm run knex -- seed:run",

When I run this command with knex, I get the following error:
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

When I run the command with knex.cmd "knex": "npm i && npx ts-node node_modules/.bin/knex.cmd", I get this error:
@ECHO off
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I would be so grateful for any help!
(I made sure knex.cmd is using CRLF for end of line sequence and UTF-8 encoding.)

I don't see anything here related to "firebase functions". What you have here looks only related to running a knex migration using nodejs.  Please edit the question to be clear how Firebase is involved at all (or if not, remove the references to it).

@DougStevenson the reason I'm running these is to locally set up my firebase functions

Tags are only to used when a level of expertise is required to answer the question.  Since Firebase expertise isn't required here, I'm going to update the question to be more accurate.

@DougStevenson ohh okay, thank you for the clarification! I haven't used stackoverflow before. Any ideas on how to fix the above problem?
